# How to this warning fixed react owl carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, helper, owl-carousel, react-dom

I am tried to this error .please help me. .how to fixed this warning.. I using react project to owl-carousel and this return warning.. how to solve this warning

### warning:

react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Using UNSAFE _component Will Receive Props in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

- Move data fetching code or side effects to component Did Up date.
- If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use me  techniques or move it to static get Derived State From Props. Learn more at: https://reactjs.org/link/derived-state

Please update the following components: React Owl Carousel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.